# AVAHI Daemon doesn't work on RPI

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+, dns, lighttpd

I have installed lighttpd on my RPI 3 :

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd
```

I have managed to access the web server from /home/pi/www
And it works, I can find my Hello World when I entered 192.168.2.31 in my URL browser.

Now I try to access my raspberry pi through mDns. In this way I have installed AVAHI :

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon libavahi-client-dev
```

I have modified my hostname :

```
Sudo raspi-config
```

and then select Network option then select Hostname then I have called it raspberrypik

I have updated my reboot system :

```
sudo update-rc.d avahi-daemon defaults
```

Now I try to access my web server from my browser, from either Windows 10 where Itunes is installed and my smartphone (I shared the Hotspot of my cellphone with the RPI) by typing raspberrypik.local but nothing happen.

Some tutorials use AVAHI to get acces on the RPI through SSH. I tried to access my RPI via SSH with raspberrypik.local, but nothing...

I have tried what is indicated in this post : [How to debug avahi-daemon? Hostname not coming through](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22485/how-to-debug-avahi-daemon-hostname-not-coming-through)

But when I do

```
$ ls -l /etc/avahi/services/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 243 Aug  2 05:53 ssh.service
```

The folder **multiple.service** and **udisks.service** are not present, is it normal ?

When I do :

```
$ avahi-browse -a
-bash: avahi-browse: command not found
```

When I ping I get :

```
~ $ ping -c 4 raspberrypik
PING raspberrypik (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from raspberrypik (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from raspberrypik (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from raspberrypik (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
64 bytes from raspberrypik (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms

--- raspberrypik ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3098ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.076/0.096/0.108/0.015 ms
```

Now if I follow the post I get :

```
~ $ avahi-resolve
-bash: avahi-resolve: command not found
```

And finally :

```
~ $ tcpdump -i wlan0 port 5353 or igmp -w /tmp/mdns.pcap
-bash: tcpdump: command not found
```

Ok I do things wrong, but where ??

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a DHCP server running on your network?

Comment: No I don't think, the IP address is attributed by the router of the room. Do you have any idea about my problem ?

Comment: No not really. One idea was that there is a DHCP server. Then avahi will not configure a link-local address from address block 169.254.0.0/16. With `avahi-tools` you have installed now you can browse and discover services. Maybe you have to use them with `sudo`. To use *tcpdump* you have to install it with `sudo apt install tcpdump` and has to run with `sudo`. If avahi has configured a link-local address then you address your RasPi with `raspberrypik.local`. Look with `ip addr` what ip address your RasPi has.

Comment: Ping the RasPi from your Windows pc. Local ping as you did always work with response from local ip address `127.0.1.1` defined in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I looked at `ip addr` and it displays the WANL0 with the IP address attributed by the DHCP of the router. I have watched the content of the folder `/etc/hosts` and it contains this  : `27.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypik
` . Eventually, I ping raspberrypik (and raspberrypik.local) from windows connected to the same network and nothing ....

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

> I have updated my reboot system `sudo update-rc.d...`

This is an obsolete or at least deprecated methodology on current versions of Raspbian and GNU/Linux generally.  Instead:

```
systemctl list-unit-files "*avahi*"
```

Should give you the service name, then:

```
sudo systemctl enable [avahi.service]
```

Or whatever the correct name is there.

> `-bash: avahi-browse: command not found`

To search packages for a specific executable command:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
apt-file search "bin/avahi-browse"
```

I think you will find this is in the `avahi-utils` package, which is probably not a dependency for any of the other avahi packages you installed.

> tcpdump: command not found

Same thing:

```
apt-file search "bin/tcpdump"
```

Comment: To search for unit files I would prefer `systemctl list-unit-files *avahi*` you also see the status.

Comment: @Ingo Thanks, I wasn't aware of that one -- just that plain `list-units` only includes things "currently in memory".   Also hadn't noticed most of that stuff accepts glob patterns!

Comment: @goldilocks thank you a lot ! I have installed the packages avahi-utils but now how can I do to get mDns working ?

Comment: Enable the systemd service.  I actually don't use avahi, but I believe based on what people have said about it here that it should be pretty easy.